# How to make iso image of current logged in system to use it as future installation media

Tags: 13.04, backup, iso

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.04 and due to installation of faulty media and different programs, my ubuntu crashed more than 7 times in last 3 days, Nvidia was the leading cause in 7 failure, and each time i had to install approx 600-700 mb of different application for my suite, like `QT creator` and `Virtual Box`, and different other apps.

Now, I don't want to trouble myself to install them again , all i want is to make image of my current Installation, so that all i have to do is burn current iso in bootable pen drive and install them as it is.

Please give me option of verified source list download only..

I recently visited remastersys, and the text written on front page seems like to me, it might have been compromised, and if it is the case, than may be his package is backdoored, so i don't want to risk myself in using such binary.

Are there valid , verified and secured way to make my current installation into ISO image, so that it can be used to burn it into some USB for bootable purpose.

**Update** I don't want to download again any of already downloaded file, all i want is to use is same downloaded file.

***Important*** Does ubuntu has no such built in verified application which can do some sort of system-restore or create backup of whole system, so that there is no re-installation required whenever system is in trouble

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Your question seems to be a duplicate of other questions in this site. Please check, for example: http://askubuntu.com/q/9135/58950 and http://askubuntu.com/q/55899/58950,

Comment: no , actually i don't even want to go and download all those stuff again. I just want to use already downloaded app. I don't want to waste my time in installing 700mb files again. I have limited internet resource of 20GB and doing this every time will be trouble for me.

Comment: In that case, please refer to http://askubuntu.com/q/85442/58950 and http://askubuntu.com/q/190133/58950. Please note that with `remastersys` (no longer in development but still available from their repository) and `relinux` you might have problems with the size of your `.iso` (i.e., it shouldn't exceed 4 GiB).

Comment: i tried ubuntubuilder, i am running 13.04 and after installation when i run it, it just show loading image and than vanishes out. Nothing comes in, i tried 3 time and each time same error.

Comment: I just don't understand, does ubuntu has no such built in verified application which can do some sort of system-restore or create backup of whole system, so that there is no re-installation required whenever system is in trouble ? crazy

Comment: this sounds like a perfect [feature request](http://askubuntu.com/q/28440/58950).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that remastersys is safe. Just add the line on the site to /etc/apt/sources.list and run `sudo apt-get install remastersys-gui; sudo remastersys-gui` and follow the on screen wizard.

Comment: sorry bro, don't take it otherwise, But i just want to know, how did you verified the binary is safe to use..

Comment: @HrithikRoshan I've been using it for as long as I can remember. (I even made a backup yesterday!) And never had an issue.

Comment: term `issue` is different than term `backdoored`.